# How do I make bazel honour the CC environment variable on Windows?

Tags: c++, environment-variables, bazel, msys2

I'm trying to use bazel to build a program against mingw32 on Windows. There isn't a built-in compiler for this, so I have to try and fake it somehow.

On Linux, I can compile against any gcc-like compiler with this:

```
CC=path-to-some-compiler-gcc bazel build ...
```

This doesn't work on Windows, obviously, since bazel defaults to using MSVC, which I don't have. But this also doesn't work --- the `CC` variable is ignored:

```
CC=path-to-some-compiler-gcc bazel build --compiler=mingw_windows
```

Is there a way to get the same behaviour I'm seeing on Linux, but on Windows?

Answer (score 0):

`VAR=value command` is a bash-like syntax so obviously `CC=path-to-some-compiler-gcc bazel build ...` won't work if you don't use any shells like that. To use that you must install bash or similar shells on Windows. In native Windows shells (cmd and PowerShell) the variable is set separately. You need to do like this in cmd:

```
set "CC=path-to-some-compiler-gcc"
bazel build --compiler=mingw_windows
```

and like this in PowerShell

```
$env:CC = "path-to-some-compiler-gcc"
bazel build --compiler=mingw_windows
```

In MSYS2 you'll need `export CC=path-to-some-compiler-gcc` to make the environment variable available to Win32 apps, otherwise the variable will be contained in the current bash session only

Comment: Sorry, should have been clearer --- I am actually doing this from the msys2 shell, so it's all running under bash.

Comment: @DavidGiven use `export CC=path-to-some-compiler-gcc`, otherwise the variable won't be exported to Windows environment

Comment: I have already verified that the environment variable is being propagated into bazel.